# invalid arrayify value

Tags: arrays

I have a question about this proof, I don’t understand why when I remove “the transaction works, and when I leave it” it gives me an error[image]

Comment: try removing the double quotes

Comment: it worked, but why? @Zartaj Afser

Comment: We don't need double quotes while calling from Etherscan. I haven't researched the reason.